# How to update multiple mysql fields with an update button using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table in my database with a few fields. I am using this form to select data from this table:

```
<form id="#" name="#"  method= "post" action="cms_order_detail.php"> 
    <table width="100%" border="1" align="center"> 
        <th> Item </th>
        <th> Price </th>
        <th> Active </th>
        <tr> 
        <?php 
        $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product` where `item_id` = '$id' AND `type`=0 ");
        while($row= mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $price      =   $row['price'];
            $item_id    =   $row['item_id'];
            $size       =   $row['size'];
        ?>
            <td class="price"> <?php echo $size;?>  </td>
            <td class="price" width="1px"> 
                <input type="number" name="pro_price" id="pro_price" value="<?php echo $price;?>" style="width:4.2em; " > 
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="number" name="onof" id="onof" value="<?php echo $row['active'];?>" style="width:2.5em; " min="0" max="1" title="1= active and 0= De-active"> 
            </td>
        </tr>   
        <?php }?>
    </table> 
    <button class="updateBtn"> Update </button> 
    <div style="clear:both"> </div>
</form>
```

I have to update the table using MySQL and PHP. How to do it? The screenshot of my web page is as below.

[image: Screen Shot]

When I click up update button the above rows should be updated. Please see the image for clear message.

Comment: Have you tried anyways to do it? Also are you using JQuery AJAX or AJAX or simple PHP/MySQL?

Comment: You used `item_id = '$id'` in you query; are you fetching single product details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Front view code(for display):**

```
<form id="frm_update" name="frm_update"  method= "post" action="cms_order_detail.php"> 
    <table width="100%" border="1" align="center"> 
        <th> Item </th>
        <th> Price </th>
        <th> Active </th>
        <tr> 
        <?php 
        $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product` where `item_id` = '$id' AND `type`=0 ");
        while($row= mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $price      =   $row['price'];
            $item_id    =   $row['item_id'];
            $size       =   $row['size'];
        ?>
            <td class="price"> <?php echo $size;?>  </td>
            <td class="price" width="1px"> 
                <input type="number" name="pro_price[]" id="pro_price" value="<?php echo $price;?>" style="width:4.2em; " > 
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="number" name="onof[]" id="onof" value="<?php echo $row['active'];?>" style="width:2.5em; " min="0" max="1" title="1= active and 0= De-active"> 
            </td>
            <input type="hidden" name="item_id[]" value="<?php print($item_id);?>"/>
        </tr>   
        <?php }?>
    </table> 
    <input type='submit' name='submit' Value='Update' class="updateBtn"/>
    <div style="clear:both"> </div>
</form>
```

**Back end code(For update):**

```
<?php
    /**
    * YOUR CONNECTION...
    *$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    *mysql_select_db("phppot_examples",$conn);
    **/

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"]!="") {
        $item_idCount = count($_POST["item_id"]);
        for($i=0; $i<$item_idCount; $i++) {
            mysql_query("UPDATE users set price='" . $_POST["pro_price"][$i] . "', active='" . $_POST["onof"][$i] . "' WHERE item_id ='" . $_POST["item_id"][$i] . "'");
        }
    header("Location:MYFRONTURL.php");
}
?>
```

**Warning:**
This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

**UPDATE:**

Used `<input type='submit' name='submit' Value='Update' class="updateBtn"/>` instead `<button class="updateBtn"> Update </button>`.

This should work!

Comment: For  this warning , you have to  convert code as per  MySQLi. Please  review  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

Comment: Boss, it does not works, I dont know what is wrong with this.

Comment: @bc120200427SaleemJafar: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks..! Glad to help!

Comment: Now, as it is accepted as "Best Answer". I would request the person, who has down voted my answer to make it neutral please. That would be really great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For that  you have to make  changes  in above code because, for this  code we can not  find  which value will be associated with which row?

```
 <?php 
     $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product` where `item_id` = '$id' AND `type`=0 ");
     while($row= mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
         $price= $row['price'];
         $item_id=   $row['item_id'];    
         $size=  $row['size'];
?>
<td class="price"><?php echo $size;?>  </td>
<td class="price" width="1px"> 
    <input type="number" name="pro_price-$row['item_id']" id="pro_price-$row['item_id']" value="<?php echo $price;?>" style="width:4.2em; " > 
</td>
<td align="center">
    <input type="number" name="onof_$row['item_id']" id="onof_$row['item_id']" value="<?php echo $row['active'];?>" style="width:2.5em; " min="0" max="1" title="1= active and 0= De-active"> 
</td>
</tr>   
<?php }?>
```

Now you get all the value with different name, when you **print($_REQUEST);** you will get all then value of with different name.  you have to extract item_id  from each variable using - and  run update  query in for loop or while loop.

Comment: I have a query in mysql like this: (Select * form table where id=1;  ) and against id = 1 i have more 4 - 5  fields, I am getting  these with (While( $row= mysql_fetch_array query)) This print the above image result. I want to update each and every value like price, name, active

Comment: for update  query  you  can try (update  table set col ='value'  where id =1)

Comment: Please review http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp. Still you face issue  please let know what is issue you are facing

Answer (score 0):

You need all IDs. You can do that by issuing, in the foreach, this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row['item_id']; ?>" />
```

This will result in HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="1" />
...
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="6" />
```

and in $_POST['id'] being an array containing 1,2 and so on.

You could also put in HTML:

```
<input type="number" name="pro_price[<?php echo $row['item_id']; ?>]" />
<input type="number" name="onof[<?php echo $row['item_id']; ?>]" />
```

so that $pro_price=$_POST['pro_price'],$onof=$_POST['onof'] would be a vector with the same keys as the values of id, and therefore:

```
foreach($id as $id1)
{
// Pseudocode
UPDATE... SET pro_price=$pro_price[$id1],onof=$onof[$id1] WHERE id = $id1;
}
```

This way you have one SUBMIT, and multiple UPDATEs.